# extract vowels in a word and add values of vowels R programming Data science

Tags: r, string, subset

I am new to Programming, We have been asked to do a Project

I have values of all letters (dataset1)

```
Letter  value
  a     1
  b     2
  c     3
  d     4
  .
  .
  .
  .
  Z     26
```

I have a list of many words (dataset2)

```
Wood
Table
Chair
Desk
```

I need to extract all vowels from the words and add up their values of vowels and store it back against respective words in dataset 2 in a separate column.

Desired Output

```
   Word         Sum_of_vowel_value

   Wood                 30        (15+15)
   Table                 6         (1+5)
   Chair                10         (9+1)
```

I am new to stack overflow. Pl excuse errors if any in posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one crude approach in base R :

Split every character in `Word` column of `dataset2`, keep only vowels and `match` it with `dataset1`'s `Letter` to get corresponding `value` and `sum` it.

```
dataset2$Sum_of_vowel_value <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(dataset2$Word), ""), 
       function(x) sum(dataset1$value[match(vowel[match(tolower(x), vowel)], 
                            dataset1$Letter)], na.rm = TRUE))

dataset2
#   Word Sum_of_vowel_value
#1  Wood                 30
#2 Table                  6
#3 Chair                 10
#4  Desk                  5
```

---

To understand this better we can break the function in steps.

We first split `Word` into separate characters

```
strsplit(as.character(dataset2$Word), "")
#[[1]]
#[1] "W" "o" "o" "d"

#[[2]]
#[1] "T" "a" "b" "l" "e"

#[[3]]
#[1] "C" "h" "a" "i" "r"

#[[4]]
#[1] "D" "e" "s" "k"
```

The next step is to keep only vowels.

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(dataset2$Word), ""), 
        function(x) vowel[match(tolower(x), vowel)])

#[[1]]
#[1] NA  "o" "o" NA 

#[[2]]
#[1] NA  "a" NA  NA  "e"

#[[3]]
#[1] NA  NA  "a" "i" NA 

#[[4]]
#[1] NA  "e" NA  NA
```

Now for these vowels, we get corresponding value from `dataset1`

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(dataset2$Word), ""), 
      function(x) dataset1$value[match(vowel[match(tolower(x), vowel)], 
                                        dataset1$Letter)])

#[[1]]
#[1] NA 15 15 NA

#[[2]]
#[1] NA  1 NA NA  5

#[[3]]
#[1] NA NA  1  9 NA

#[[4]]
#[1] NA  5 NA NA
```

Finally, we sum all these values to get final output as :

```
#[1] 30  6 10  5
```

**data**

```
vowel <- c('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
dataset1 <- data.frame(Letter = letters, value = 1:26)
dataset2 <- structure(list(Word = structure(c(4L, 3L, 1L, 2L), 
.Label = c("Chair", "Desk", "Table", "Wood"), class = "factor")), 
row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: this works .... though we are yet to get to sapply function in our course :).. thanks a lot..

Comment: I spent some time on your solution.. but not able to get the logic. Would you be able to explain especially the part post function (x) ? I suppose this is a little beyond what we have covered so far..

Comment: @Jonathan I added step by step description of the code. See if that helps you to understand the code better.

Comment: Thanks.. I really appreciate the efforts you guys are putting to help a newbie!!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't reached `apply` in your course yet, perhaps you've reached for loops and regular expressions?

Extract the vowels using `gsub` by substituting non-vowels with empty space:

```
dataset2$Vowels <- gsub("[^aeiou]", "", tolower(dataset2$Word))
```

Split the string vectors into individual letters.

```
vowels <- strsplit(dataset2$Vowels, "")
```

Initialise the scores

```
dataset2$Score <- 0
```

Use a `for` loop to count the values of the vowels using `match`.

```
for(i in 1:length(vowels)){
  dataset2$Score[i] <- sum(dataset1$value[match(vowels[[i]], dataset1$Letter)], na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

---

```
dataset2
#   Word Vowels Score
#1  Wood     oo    30
#2 Table     ae     6
#3 Chair     ai    10
#4  Desk      e     5
```

A for loop is basically the same as using `sapply` but a lot slower.